# Accessing items individually in a popup menu for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm making a simple popup menu for Android following the example from Xamarin's website http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/popup_menus/ .
I get the popup when clicking on the button. What i'm interested in though, is how to get each item in the popup to do something different, like just displaying a toast or changing the layout. I basically have this:

```
showPopupMenu.Click += (s, arg) => {              
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (this, showPopupMenu);
menu.Inflate (Resource.Menu.popup_menu);

menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} selected", arg1.Item.TitleFormatted);
};

menu.DismissEvent += (s2, arg2) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("menu dismissed"); 
};
    menu.Show ();
```

};

And I expect it to be done under the MenuItemClick, but I just can't figure out what to write to access each individually.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu (this,tvEmail);
        menu.Inflate (Resource.Menu.popup_menu);
        menu.MenuItemClick += (s1, arg1) => {
            switch(arg1.Item.TitleFormatted.ToString())
            {
            case "Edit":
                //Edit action here
                break;
            }
```